# Better Understanding Errors

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am a beginner in SML. It's something easy but it took like hours and yet I cant solve it.

I have to take a list of string and invert every string as well as list. and do everything without defining multiple functions outside the main. e.g. ["stack","overflow","nice"] would give ["ecin","wolfrevo","kcats"]

```
fun oppositelist(l)=foldl (op::) nil (map ((fn(x)=>(implode o rev o explode)(x)), l));
```

and the error message is:

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: 'Z -> 'Y
  operand:         (string -> string) * 'X
  in expression:
    map ((fn x => <exp> <exp>),l)
```

Don't solve everything, if the method is wrong. Hint it. Its a homework question.

Thank You.

Comment: Answered and then downvoted anyway, as I believe this is the sort of question you should take to your TA rather than "clutter up" StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SML function `map` is [curried](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). To map a function `f` over every element of the list `l`, you must write `map f l`. What you wrote is `map (f,l)`, which means "map the function `(f,l)` over... something to be determined later." The compiler is complaining at you because `(f,l)` is *not* a function (`'Z -> 'Y`); it's a tuple consisting of a function and a list (`(string -> string) * 'X`).

I haven't looked any closer at your solution, but if you comment in response to this answer and ask me to, I probably will. :)

**EDIT:** Oh, and `(fn(x)=>(implode o rev o explode)(x))` is just a long-winded way of writing `(implode o rev o explode)`, for the same reason that writing `(fn(x)=>f(x))` is a long-winded way of writing `f`.

Comment: Thanks! That was the only fault with the code! It now works! :)